# Avoiding default logic for case partial function

Tags: scala

I have the following code in multiple places in my application

```
(i: Option) => {
    case Some(i) => // doSomething with i
    case None => 
}
```

The doSomething will vary in each location, but any time I have a None I don't want to do anything.

Is there an easy way to avoid the use of `case None =>` using implicits or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `map` or a `foreach` - these won't do anything if your `Option` is a `None`.  The difference between the two is that `map` will return an `Option` while `foreach` returns a `Unit`

```
iOpt.map(i => /* doSomething with i */) // does nothing and returns a None if iOpt is a None
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are discarding the result, then you can use `foreach`:

```
o.foreach(i => doSomething(i))
```

If you need the result of `doSomething`, then use `map`:

```
o.map(i => doSomething(i))
```

Comment: this is the preferred method. foreach is specifically for aide effects; map is what you're doing transforms and want to retain an output.